# How to reproduce android.view.lnflateException

Tags: android, xml, runtimeexception, inflate-exception

How to naturally invoke `android.view.InflateException` whilst instantiation a layout XML file into a corresponding View object? Erasure of the constructor with AttributeSet parameter and `throw` is prohibited.

Use set of typical constructors:

```
public TestView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.gridViewStyle);
}

public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridView, defStyle, 0);

    int hSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridView_horizontalSpacing, 0);
    setHorizontalSpacing(hSpacing);

    int vSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridView_verticalSpacing, 0);
    setVerticalSpacing(vSpacing); 

    int index = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridView_stretchMode, STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
    if (index >= 0) {
        setStretchMode(index);
    }

    int columnWidth = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridView_columnWidth, -1);
    if (columnWidth > 0) {
        setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
    }

    int numColumns = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridView_numColumns, 1);
    setNumColumns(numColumns);

    index = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.GridView_gravity, -1);
    if (index >= 0) {
        setGravity(index);
    }

    a.recycle();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, especially given the constraints. However, any `Exception` coming out from `View` constructor will do, see http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#594

Comment: The purpose of this is to determine an origin of inflation error for `TestView` which extends `AbsListView` while changing the view instance from the class to `GridView` one turns off the issue and runtime become safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [InflateException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InflateException.html) inherits from RuntimeException you can throw it freely